# Find the maximum and minimum of the function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a self-adjoint linear operator (i.e., $\langle Lx,y\rangle=\langle x,Ly\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$). Let $1\leq k\leq n$ be an integer, for every $k$-tuple of orthonormal vectors $(u_1,\cdots,u_k)$, we define $Q(u_1,\cdots,u_k)$ by 
$$Q(u_1,\cdots,u_k):=\sum_{i=1}^k \langle Lu_i,u_i\rangle.$$
Find the maximum of and minimum of $Q$.

I know that in the case $k=1$, the maximum and minimum of $Q$ is the maximum and minimum of the eignvalues of $T$, but I don't know how to deal with the general case?

Answer (score 0):

Since $L$ is self-adjoint on the finite-dimensional real inner product space,
there exists an orthonormal basis $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $L$ corresponding to eigenvalues
$\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n.$
Now, given an $k$-tuple of orthonormal vectors $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, write
$$u_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j,\quad\forall 1\leq i\leq k,$$
for some scalars $a_{ij}$. Note that it is clear that $\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2=\langle u_i,u_i\rangle=1$ for eaach $i$. Then we have
\begin{align}
Q(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k)
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle Lu_i,u_i\rangle
 =\sum_{i=1}^k\left\langle L\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j\right),
  \sum_{l=1}^na_{il}x_l\right\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\left\langle \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}Lx_j,
  \sum_{l=1}^na_{il}x_l\right\rangle
 =\sum_{i=1}^k\left\langle \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}\lambda_jx_j,
  \sum_{l=1}^na_{il}x_l\right\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}\lambda_j\left\langle x_j,
  \sum_{l=1}^na_{il}x_l\right\rangle
 =\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2\lambda_j.
\end{align}
Observe that 
$$Q(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k)
  \leq\lambda_1+\sum_{i=2}^k\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2\lambda_j=Q(x_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k)$$
Note that we only use the normality between $x_1$ and $u_i$s, not the orthogonality, so we may
temporarily replace $u_1$ by $x_1$ in $Q$. Next, since each $x_i$ corresponds to an $\lambda_i$ uniguely, we may not find
an another $x_i'\in\mathbb{R}^n$, which is linearly independent to $x_i$, that corresponds to $\lambda_i$ again. Therefore
$$Q(x_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k)
  \leq\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\sum_{i=3}^k\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2\lambda_j=Q(x_1,x_2,u_3,\ldots,u_k).$$
Continue this process, we conclude that 
$$Q(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k)\leq\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i=Q(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k),$$
that is, the maximum of $Q$ is $\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i$.
Similarly, the minimum is 
$$Q(x_{n-k+1},x_{n-k+2},\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_{n-k+i}.$$